# MySQL counting duplicate fields within a query

Tags: mysql

I have the following query

```
SELECT m.uid
      ,m.ttime
      ,m.mac
      ,m.vendor
      ,m.ssid
      ,m.rssi
      ,k.note1
      ,k.note2 
FROM monitor m 
LEFT OUTER JOIN known k ON m.mac=k.mac
WHERE (`ttime` > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) 
AND (monitor.mac !='b8:27:eb:91:b5:bb')
ORDER BY monitor.uid desc
```

This is formatted into a table. I would like the table to have an extra column giving the number of times monitor.mac appears in the table. This would indicate if it is new, or a regular occurrence.

The SQL query is passed as a string to the a php page for display purposes, so I am limited to adjusting the query, rather than using another variable with its own query.

Edited to add an example output line from the existing query:

```
3637
2017-10-29 08:57:20
6c:88:14:2e:cc:fc
Intel Corporate
GHC
-65
NULL
NULL
```

*would like to add the number of times this MAC has appeared*

Comment: You want the query results to have this additional count field?

Comment: may be helpful to give example table data, and example output

Comment: Yes, another field showing the number of times that monitor.mac appears in the table. Example data added to the qurestion

Comment: example data:  3637 2017-10-29 08:57:20
6c:88:14:2e:cc:fc
Intel Corporate
GHC
-65
NULL
NULL

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `GROUP BY` along with the conditional search if you like a specific monitor to list the number of times it's repeated.

```
SELECT m.uid
      ,m.ttime
      ,m.mac
      ,m.vendor
      ,m.ssid
      ,m.rssi
      ,k.note1
      ,k.note2 
FROM monitor m 
LEFT OUTER JOIN known k ON m.mac=k.mac
WHERE (`ttime` > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) 
AND (monitor.mac !='b8:27:eb:91:b5:bb')
GROUP BY monitor.mac
HAVING count(*) > 1
ORDER BY monitor.uid desc
```